# On the meaning of "$5$ mod $691$"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Harvard mathematician Barry Mazur wrote the following (page 223 of Gold and Simons 2008).

“Is 5 mod 691 to be thought of as a symbol, or as a stand in for any number that has remainder 5 when divided by 691, or should we take the tack that it (i.e., “5 mod 691”) is the equivalence class of all integers that are congruent to 5 mod 691?”

Comment: Ok --- but what is your question?

Comment: Actually, given like this I'd say  it's just $5$.

Comment: The answer is in the text, even given before this rhetorical question is asked, it is "all three ways."

Comment: Context is crucial. When $\bmod$ is used as a binary operator, as it not infrequently is nowadays, $5\bmod{691}$ is by definition the number $5$. For either of the other interpretations some other notation is preferable, precisely to avoid this ambiguity.

Comment: Well, from personal experience I can say I came to grieve first interpreting it as an operation.  (It *IS* the number 5).  That was intuitive and easy but it made more advanced math harder when I hit it.  As equivalence class is the most abstract and hardest to comprehend but when you do it is the the most valuable.  I'd really recommend getting use to thinking it this way as soon as possible.  It could be agrued as a stand in is the most practical for problem solving.

Answer (score 3):

I think the implicit answer to your implicit question is "it depends". Each of the three interpretations (and there are others) can be correct and useful in the appropriate context and for the right audience.

To know why Mazur raised the question we'd need more of the context in which it appears. In his comment

> The answer is in the text, even given before this rhetorical question
>   is asked, it is "all three ways."

@quid provides that context.

Comment: The context is here http://www.math.harvard.edu/~mazur/preprints/when_is_one.pdf Mazur "raised the question" as a rhetorical device.  And  leaves no doubt regarding the answer, which is the same as yours. (To avoid confusion I commented based on the pre-edit version.)

Answer (score 0):

Taking your question to be Mazur's, the answer is none of these options: "$5$ mod $691$" is not a well-formed piece of mathematical syntax. An example of a (more complete) well-formed sentence is $$696\equiv5\;(\mathrm{mod}\,691).$$The parentheses here are important: The "mod $691$" does not relate to the "$5$" but rather functions as an adverbial phrase qualifying the verb "$\equiv$". It might be more logical, albeit not conventional, to write it as $$696\equiv\!\!\!\!_{\mod\!\! 691}\,5.$$There could be various notations for $\{5+691n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$; but "$5$ mod $691$" isn't a good one---nor is it a good notation for an arbitrary member of that set when the choice doesn't matter.